# What is IllegalOrphanException?

Tags: java, exception, netbeans

I'm working on a Java project using NetBeans.

I created entities from the DB and also created JPAControllers from the entities. When i use the method `edit(Entity e)` which is located in the JPA controller, I get `IllegalOrphanException`. The class `IllegalOrphanException` is generated with the JPAControllers. I tried to search for it but there is nothing.

What is this Exception?

Comment: Maybe its documentation explains it? Or its code? Or at least the code throwing it, or even its stack trace? Or maybe all that is irrelevant and we, extra-luci wizards, should guess with our crystal ball?

Comment: @JBNizet, please answer the question or contribute. Assuming that he's referring to `dbcontrollers.exceptions.IllegalOrphanException`, the documentation is severely lacking.

Comment: Here's a thought.  Look up the method that is throwing that exception. Its javadoc should (ideally) describe what exceptions it can throw, and under what circumstances it throws them. The empty IllegalOrphanException javadoc page may have simply been an oversight.

JB Nizet is right, though; it would indeed be very helpful to have a stack trace and mention of method. We could have an answer from details like that.